# Not encoding already encoded items with htmlentities

Tags: php, html

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
Bürstner &nbsp;&nbsp;
```

When I use htmlentities() on it, I set the `double encode` param to false, but it still ends up re-encoding the `&nbsp;` into `&amp;nbsp;`

I'm using this to encode:

```
$out = htmlentities($string,ENT_NOQUOTES, 0);
```

Am I somehow misunderstanding how this works? The desired output is to encode the umlaut u, but leave the existing nbsp entities alone (this is just an example, there are MANY entities in a *very long* document already).

** EDIT **

Since this seems unclear, ORIGINAL STRING:

`Bürstner &nbsp;&nbsp;`

DESIRED OUTPUT:

`B&uuml;rstner &nbsp;&nbsp;`

The existing entities should be left alone.

Comment: Have you tried using htmlspecialchars?  http://us3.php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't encode umlauts

Comment: And you really need that characters to be replaced? What character encoding do you use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The third parameter of [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) is the *charset* parameter; the fourth parameter is the *double_encode* parameter. So try this:

```
$out = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, ini_get('default_charset'), false);
```

Answer (score 4):

The third argument is the charset; you need to set the fourth, not the third, to false.

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd parameter of htmlentities is the charset.. you would need to set the 4th to false

> string htmlentities  ( string $string 
>   [, int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT  [,
>   string $charset  [, bool
>   $double_encode = true  ]]] )

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you overlooked [**the third parameter**](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) to `htmlentities()`:

> string htmlentities  ( string $string  [, int $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT  [, string $charset  [, bool $double_encode = true  ]]] )

try

```
$out = htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, <whatever encoding you're using>, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this function

The link for it
http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlspecialchars.php

```
<?php
function special_formatting($input) {
    $output = htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES);
    $output = str_replace(array('  ', "\n"), array('&nbsp;&nbsp;', '<br>'), $output);
    return str_replace('&nbsp; ', '&nbsp;&nbsp;', $output);
}
?>
```